# C guessing game, Loop eror

Tags: c

I am making a simple guessing game in C, but when the guess is correct it wont exit the loop. Prob a dumb question but I am new to C. Below is a copy of the code if anyone can help thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int getGuess()
{
    int guess;
    printf("Enter your guess: ");
    scanf("%d", &guess);
    return guess;
}
int playGuessingGame()
{
    int guess = getGuess();
    int answer = sqrt(rand() % 100 + 10);
    bool solved = false;
    while (!solved)
    {
        if (guess == answer)
        {
            printf("You got it!\n");
            solved = true;
            break;
        }
        else if (guess < answer)
        {
            printf("To Low!\n");
            guess = getGuess();
        }
        else
        {
            printf("To High!\n");
            guess = getGuess();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int main(void)
{
    printf("Welcome to the guessing game!\n");
    while (1) // infinite loop
    {
        printf("\nEnter Y to play or Q to quit: "); // ask for each iteration
        char input;
        scanf(" %c", &input); // Use " %c" to consume leading whitespace left over.

        if (input == 'Q') // break infinite loop
        {
            break;
        }
        if (input == 'Y')
        {
            playGuessingGame();
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid input\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to make it so only the print statement goes through, and it doesnt ask for the guess again.

Comment: Seems to be some code missing...

Comment: I can send you more code from the file what else is needed @Fe2O3

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically you'll have to post a [mre].

Comment: How is this function called? It could be that some other loop is causing this function to be repeatedly called..

Comment: @Fe2O3 This is the loop where it is called

Comment: What is the problem with the function you show? What happens when you build with it? What happens when you run your program? What is supposed to happen? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: printf("Welcome to the guessing game!\n");
    printf("Enter Y to play or Q to quit: ");
    char input;
    scanf("%c", &input);
    while (input != 'Q')
    {
        if (input == 'Y')
        {
            playGuessingGame();
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid input\n");
        }
    }

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude When it is ran and the correct answer is entered it will still say "Enter your guess: ". When i want it to only say "You got it"

Comment: `while (input != 'Q') { if (input == 'Y') { playGuessingGame(); } else { printf("Invalid input\n");` So-o-o-o the value of `input` is always `'Y'` and this loop is re-running the same function... Easy when you show your code...

Comment: You need another `scanf("%c", &input);` at the end of the loop. And also better check the return value from `scanf`.

Comment: Also please change `scanf("%c", &input);` to `scanf(" %c", &input);` Note the leading space in the format string. The `%c` format will otherwise read *all* characters, including the newline from the previous input. The leading space tells `scanf` to skip all space, including newline.

Comment: Should I put the scanf outside of the loop or in it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Rearranging the code of `main()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main( void )
{
    srand(time(NULL)); // seed the random number generator.

    printf("Welcome to the guessing game!\n");
    while (1) // infinite loop
    {
        printf("\nEnter Y to play or Q to quit: "); // ask for each iteration
        char input;
        scanf(" %c", &input); // Use " %c" to consume leading whitespace left over.
        // credit @SomeProgrammerDude

        if (input == 'Q') // break infinite loop
        {
            break;
        }
        if (input == 'Y')
        {
            playGuessingGame();
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid input\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented this code and the output is still the same. it says                   "Welcome to the guessing game!
Enter Y to play or Q to quit: Y
Enter your guess: 7
You got it!
Enter your guess: "

Comment: @MichaelFerguson Have you tried recompiling? The code in your question is _still_ incomplete, so anything is possible (including undefined behaviour.) Suggest you edit the question adding the full code so that we can compile and test for ourselves... (Otherwise, it's just a different kind of guessing game that attracts _downvotes_...)

Comment: Ill put the whole file into the question

Comment: @MichaelFerguson I've just compiled and run the program. I guess the answer (always 7 because the random number generator is not initialised in your code). I get congratulations. Then I'm asked if I want to play again (Y or Q)... This is as expected.

Comment: Ok well thats good. Im not sure why mine says otherwise bc i have recomplied multiple times. i have have even tried restarting vscode but i get the same response every time

Comment: @MichaelFerguson Can't help you if it's some configuration problem on your machine. One test, though, is to add another few print statements, recompile, then run it looking for those changes... Some people have problems with IDE's... Just a wild guess...